# Disallow Interaction With Website During Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am attempting to write some javascript that will create textareas and when you click on a textarea to begin typing it grows and centers in the window until you click off of it where it shrinks back down.

Easy enough, until I wanted to add the .animate() and suddenly I have some serious problems that I am pouring too much time into trying to figure out.

While running some quality assurance I discovered a number of bugs...

-If I drop focus on the textarea that is animating its growth while it is still animating then the .blur() function fails to call.

-If I shift focus to another textarea while the first is still animating
then both may remain large failing to call the .blur() function.

-Finally there is just some really strange activity with the centering feature. .scrollTo() and .animate() perform poorly together especially when there are many textareas or I am picking a box that in the midst of many.

Is there a way to disallow any interaction with the website while an animation plays out?

Any ideas on how to remedy any of these issues?

the javascript... boxy.js
Code:

```
function growthearea() {

$('textarea.textfield').blur(function(){
    $(this).animate({ height: "51" }, 500);  //shrink the current box when lose focus
  //$(this).height(51);  
});

    $('textarea.textfield').focus(function(){

    $("*").off("focus,blur,click");  //turn off focus,blur,click while animating

    var wheretoY = $(this).offset().top-73;
    window.scrollTo(17,wheretoY);

        // turn back on focus,blur,click after animation completes
        $(this).animate({ height: "409" }, 1000, function(){("*").on("focus,blur,click")});
        //$(this).height(409);
    });


}


function newboxbtn()
{
    var btn=document.createElement("textarea");
    btn.setAttribute('class','textfield');

    var textlocale = document.getElementById('locale');
    textlocale.appendChild(btn);

    $('textarea.textfield').on('keyup change', function() {
        $('p.display').text('You are typing: ' + $(this).val());  //live update from focused textarea
    });

    growthearea();  //recall function for any new boxes to be acknowledged

};

function jsinit()
{
    $('textarea.textfield').on('keyup change', function() {
        $('p.display').text('You are typing: ' + $(this).val());  //live update from focused textarea
    });

    growthearea(); //call function for initial group of boxes
}
```

the html... boxy.htm
Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sty.css" />        
    <script src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./boxy.js"></script>
<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");
        $(window).scroll(function(){            
            $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "fast" );          
        });
        jsinit();
    });
</script>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="grid">

        <div class="col-left" id="left">
                        <div class="module" id="scrollingDiv">
            <input type="button" value="add" onclick="newboxbtn()" />
            <p class="display">you are typing </p>
            </div>
      </div> <!--div class="col-left"-->


        <div class="col-midd">
            <div class="module" id="locale">
                            <textarea class="textfield" placeholder="begin typing here..." ></textarea>
                            <textarea class="textfield" placeholder="begin typing here..."></textarea>
      </div>
        </div> <!--div class="col-midd"-->

    </div> <!--div class="grid"-->

</body>
</html>
```

the css... sty.css
Code:

```
.textfield {
    width: 97%;
    height: 51;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 70%;
    background: white;
/*  box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px 1px #0044FF;*/
}

.textfielded {
    width: 97%;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 70%;
    background: white;
/*  box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #FFDD00;*/
}


/*#postcomp {
    width: 500px;
}*/


* {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

$pad: 20px;

.grid {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 0 $pad 0;

  &:after {
    /* Or @extend clearfix */
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
  padding-right: $pad;
  .grid &:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
.col-left {
    width: 13%;
}
.col-midd {
    width: 43%;
}
.col-rght {
    width: 43%;
}

.module {
  padding: $pad;


}

/* Opt-in outside padding */
.grid-pad {
  padding: $pad 0 $pad $pad;
  [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
    padding-right: $pad;
  }
}

body {
    padding: 10px 50px 200px;
  background: #001235;

}
h1 {
  color: black;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    font-weight: 100;
}
p {
    color: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if something is animated:  { quite weird for sure! }

```
if($('*').is(':animated').length) return;
```

Comment: So this is only false while the element(s) is animatING?

Comment: No, this is true when any element is animated so it returns nothing. You need to put it at top of functions you don't want to be executed while any elements are animated. BTW, you should then remove the unbind logic